# java variable names

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

Could you give some good reasons for having the class name as part of the name of any variable? We use to have this policy, which I find quite useful. Some team member wants to revert the decision.

My arguments for the moment:

- you can directly know what you're talking about:

  for (Student student: students) {
  ...
  }

is quite easy to understand (vs *Student s* or *Student anyone*)

- it helps self-commenting the code
- our ide provides direct support for that
- you can directly see wheter you're using apples instead of pears (or bears ;-) )

Less confusion where subtle differences matter:

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(nameExpression, name);
```

The only argument I can see against this is that it makes the code longer (which I think isn't an issue with modern IDEs).

Is there public provisioning for such a recommendation? Anyone using the same rule? Any alternative?

Comment: You should name the variables so that it's clear what they contain/represent. The type is usually not important. Would you e.g. write `String string = "Eric"`?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here: is it about writing "Student student" rather than "Student s" or "Student var"?

Comment: @DJClayworth,yes he is trying to say put the tpye in front of the varaible name ex: "Student studentJack = ...."

Comment: It seems fine to do something like `Student studentJohn;`.  I agree that it makes it easier to differentiate variables later in the code.

Comment: @Trevor Arjeski. It's something that makes refactoring harder, and it only works for simple cases. What do you do with instances that implement several interfaces? What do you do if you have subclasses?

Comment: In most cases, I even find that you'll loop on all students of the list, and you only need 1 student variable, which can simply be named... "student". In case I need to differentiate, I put the type at the end, ex "Student oldStudent". BTW, that's what Netbeans suggests for variable names.

Comment: @ymajoros I don't think anyone objects against using that for simple cases, but it sounds like you want to enforce it for all variables, and then it becomes bad.

Comment: @Kaj: I've been using this on all my object references for some time (like, 3 years). I don't do it systematically on loop variables (if they aren't objects), for example. I only see benefits from this convention. Could you give me some counter-example?

Comment: @ymajoros. I did in my first post. What's the point of `String string` or `Map<?,?> map`, and what do you do if you have instances that implement several interfaces, where the actual implementing class isn't important?

Comment: @Kaj I said that variable names should *contain* the type, not that they should be restricted to that (I'll edit my question to make that clearer). I'd use String messageStr and studentGradesMap.

Comment: @Kaj: I use the declared type when there are multiple interfaces or subclasses. I declare variables using the most general type that I need (e.g. List instead of ArrayList).

Comment: Well, one good reason to not use something that looks like hungarian notation is that it was tried several years ago. E.g. Microsoft used it, but most companies have stopped using it. There must be a good reason for it. Microsoft no longer recommends using hungarian notation, and just take a look at the javadoc. Do you see hungarian notation being used there? Read the wikipedia article on hungarian notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Comment: It also only works (I use this term loosely) for simple class names.  What are the repercussions when the class is, for example ClasspathXmlApplicationContext.  I would prefer a variable like springCtx or springContext, which describes what it is.  I think this strategy will fall apart quickly in real code.

Comment: @Robin: I agree that, sometimes, I only use some parts of the class name (preferably, an interface it implements).

Comment: @Kaj: could you have some reference for this claim, preferably for Java? I started checking the Wikipedia article you mentioned, and will read further. At first sight, it doesn't say Hungarian Notation is bad. BTW, I'm convinced that this policy is related to Hungarian notation, but I don't think it's exactly that neither.

Comment: The wikipedia article both mentions that Microsoft used to use it, and that they no longer recommend it. It does also list pros and cons. What you want is almost the same as hungarian notation. It will make refactoring of code harder since you will be forced to change variable names when you change types. I can only talk out of real life experience. I used hungarian notation in C++ about 10-15 years ago, and it was a pain in the *

Comment: @ymajos, this is also an blog entry that says that Microsoft don't recommend hungarian notation for C#, and they consider txtInput as hungarian notation. The blog entry is linking to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms229045.aspx where Microsoft explicitly says `Do not use Hungarian notation.
Hungarian notation is the practice of including a prefix in identifiers to encode some metadata about the parameter, such as the data type of the identifier.` The same applies to Java.

Comment: @Kaj: why would the same apply to Java? This is Microsoft saying something about prefixes, without argumentation. I think it applies more to basic data types (int, double) than to objets. In my experience, the notation I propose here helps make things very clear. I'll try to show some longer examples. The Wikipedia article lists interesting but not definitive pros and cons. I'll definitively read it extensively.

Comment: If you can't come up with a more descriptive name than the type, go for `student`. I fall back on this only for simple things like loop variables that have a narrow scope. For anything else you're better off using a *descriptive name* which may include the type if nothing better suffices. One problem here is nothing else really stands in for a `Student`. For a map of all students with their names as keys I'd use `allStudentsByName`.

Comment: @ymajoros. What they say applies to all object oriented languages. No, they aren't just talking about basic data types. You have to realize that all companies would do what you want to do if it was a good thing. Don't you think that it's odd that most other companies don't use it if it was such a good thing? The business have tried it once, and most companies didn't like it. It was very popular about 15 years ago.

Comment: @David: I agree, *allStudentsByName* makes it somewhat clear it's a map.

Comment: @Kaj: you cite MS, but without any argumentation. I'd like to hear real arguments, not just saying that it should apply to all languages (why?). Also, I don't see any backing about companies not using or even disliking the idea.

Comment: @ymajoros - You're not going to find a proof that one method is better than the other. As with most style guidelines, you weigh both sides and make a choice as an organization. Hungarian Notation was more popular when IDEs were less powerful and before refactoring. I feel that it went by the wayside as the industry and tools matured. You'll still see it some places, but I've used it in only one of my projects since 1995, and that was because the existing codebase I extended used it.

Comment: @ymajoros. Just think of it. Why would it be bad in C# but good in Java? What are the key differences between C# and Java that would make it so good in Java, but not applicable to C#? You do see backing of my arguments, just that you don't think about it. Check the Java source code. Does it use prefixing? No. Check the javadoc. Do you see prefixing there? No. Check the javadoc for the most common open source projects. Do you see prefixing there? No. What is the conclusion? Wouldn't it be widespread if it was good? Who don't want to use good things.

Comment: @Kaj: MS says it's bad for C#, I didn't see enough reasons to believe them. So, I don't see why it would extend to anything else. I see it in some places and not in others. I see lot of spaghetti code everywhere, that doesn't mean it's the way to go.

Comment: @David: +1 for the first part: it seems I won't find definitive proof for or against it. Guess I'll just check "Code Complete" ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bible on this question is Steve McConnel's book, **[Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)**, which is the most comprehensive book on software construction practice like this. He has a whole chapter on variable naming and why it is important.

The key is to make the name a full description of what the variable does, so that it is easy to understand for the person reading it. If it achieves that, then it's good practice.

*Student student* looks like a simple to understand policy, but it has an immediate disadvantage - it contains no extra information about the variable. You already know its a student. If you know anything else about the object then add it to the variable name - studentUnderReview, graduatingStudent etc. "student" should only be used if you know absolutely nothing else, such as the variable is used to iterate over all Students. Now in a long method it's useful to know the type by just looking at the name, but if the variable has short scope then it's marginal whether its useful or not. There are some studies (see McConnel) which indicate that for variables with very short scope, such as for loop indices, short names are better.

As soon as you have two variables, this system breaks down. If the default is to call one variable "student" then the temptation is to call two variables "student1" and "student2", which is bad practice indeed (see McConnel for details). You need to make names that describe the object - goodStudent and badStudent; studentBeingSaved and studentBeingRead.

Comment: I'll definitively have a look on the book. If I have two Student variables, I usually name them in the style you suggest. My question was about a good reference on the subject, so your answer definitively is interesting.

Comment: One important topic that is only slightly touched in Code Complete is using units in the variable name. I consider putting the units in the variable a must, like timeoutMilliseconds instead of just timeout and putting the content type (that is not part of the variable type) as commentsHtml instead of just comments.

Comment: That's a good point, but if you are using a consistent set of units then it's unnecessary to put the units in the name. In the comments will suffice.

Comment: @DJClayworth The problem is that you may start with timeout being seconds and then you change it to milliseconds to have more resolution and it becomes a mess. If you rename the variable you make sure there are no references to the variable with the old units.

Comment: That's why I said "if you are using a consistent set of units". If you switch to not having a consistent set of units then yes, you may have to rename some variables.

Answer (score 7):

That sounds like [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to me.

In principle it sounds like a good idea but I'm honestly not sure there are good reasons for it:

- Self commenting / documenting code - this should be possible without putting types in the variable names;
- An IDE should also provide support for seeing what type a variable is without putting it in the variable name (e.g. Eclipse can do this)
- I don't know that this is really an advantage.

One problem with Hungarian Notation that you don't mention is that if you refactor code, you have to change all the variable names as well. There are plenty of examples on The Daily WTF where variables are named 'strSOMETHING' or 'intSOMETHING', even though the types are defined as something else.

In general, IMO the case for using Hungarian Notation is pretty flimsy and generally I wouldn't recommend making it a policy.

(If this isn't exactly what you are talking about, I apologise!)

Comment: That definitely does sound like Hungarian Notation. I can see the value in Hungarian Notation when using a loosely typed language like JavaScript but that can just lead to confusion when you expect an integer but receive an object, like the example you get.

Comment: I don't see where the example has an object when you expect an integer.

Comment: I even agree somewhat for some variables (counters). However, from my expericence, I think this should be a strict convention for objects. A "student" will probably stay as such.

Comment: BTW, most IDE can show the variable type, but this isn't obvious at first sight if you don't observe something like this.

Comment: @DJClayworth, it was an arbitrary example and was unrelated to the The Daily WTF example. It was just meant to illustrate the fact that in a loosely typed language, the type is not guaranteed to remain the same.

Comment: In terms of Java, however, I don't think it's at all necessary to prefix variables with a type since most people likely use an IDE capable of providing type information.

Comment: @alexcoco: but you have to enquire. And you don't always read code from an IDE (web...). In opposition, this policy make things clear at almost no cost (typing the type in netbeans = just pressing ctrl-space).

Comment: @ymajoros, I agree, not everyone will read the code from an IDE. Maybe it's just my personal preference not to prefix them. And I think that's important too. For me, it's enough to stop me from prefixing. Then again, when I code, it's usually for my eyes only.

Comment: A quite good blog article on what Hungarian notation was actually intended for: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: @Thomas: I should give it a try, but... it seems to be mostly about c/c++ . Is this blog a reference?

Answer (score 2):

The policy should be to use *descriptive* variable names. One-letter variable names are bad, but so are variable names based exclusively on class names. Your main argument is really for descriptive variable names.

As for the others:

- it helps self-commenting the code  - no, it duplicates information from the variable declaration
- our ide provides direct support for that - that would only be an argument if the alternatives provide no benefits
- you can directly see wheter you're using apples instead of pears (or bears ;-) ) - that's the job of the type system

Of course, if your class names are descriptive, then sometimes it will make sense to have variables with the same name - when the variable describes an instance of the class without any distinctive characteristics. As in your example:

```
for (Student student: students) { ... }
```

If you're looping over all students, this is fine. But if you have a non-generic instance of `Student`, the variable name should describe what particular role that student has in this part of the program (e.g. `candidate` or `graduate`).

Comment: I agree for some parts, until the candidate/graduate examples. To me, candidateStudent is a more appropriate choice.

Comment: I'm with Michael on this. "Student candidateStudent" adds no information over "Student candidate".

Comment: @DJClayworth it does give visual type information that "candidate" doesn't give. In our big code repository, this is quite important. You can't always have to check the type.

Comment: @ymajoros: If variables are used far from where they're defined, you have a design problem, independant of code size, and type information is not the biggest part of that problem. Any Java IDE worth using will show you the type of a variable if you hover the cursor over it. There is a very broad consensus that "Visual type information" which duplicates the declared type is NOT a good thing (see the whole Hungarian notation debate).

Comment: it doesn't need to be used far from the definition to be difficult to read. In any non-trivial algorithm, naming a Student variable "graduate" gives the reader something to remember. In contrast, explicitly naming it "graduateStudent" makes everything clear.

Answer (score 1):

Generally your variable names should help the developer see quickly what they actually represent.
`Student student` would be ok if the relation that defines expresses a anything-to-student relation, like `Student[] students` (or better some collection of Student)  would be ok for a class `Professor` or the like.

`String string` is generally a bad idea, since it doesn't say anything about the use of that variable. Better names would be `String name`, `String description` or similar. In some cases, where all that matters is that you're dealing with one string - like general string utilities - you might call the variable `string` but if you have two or more, you should use better names (e.g. `source` and `target` etc. depending on the class/method).

IMHO, adding prefixes/suffixes might be a good idea if they tell you something about the variable that its base name wouldn't, e.g. in a web environment you might deal with strings that are input by the user as well as escaped strings (e.g. to prevent code injection), so you might use a prefix/suffix to make a disctinction between the user input version and the escaped counterpart.

Comment: I agree that String string isn't a good idea (in most cases; could be in a string utility method). But I always end my variable names with Str when they contain the string representation of something (which, in OOP, should be very different from the thing it represents).

Comment: @ymajoros you can do that if you have a string representation of something that isn't a string, but if you have a plain string object, you wouldn't call it `nameStr` for example, would you?

Comment: I wouldn't if it's obvious. I would if it needs to: *String publicationDateStr* (formatted date) vs *Date publicationDate*